# Is Object a datatype?

Tags: java, oop, jakarta-ee

It is a basic unit of Object-Oriented Programming and represents real-life entities.  A typical Java program creates many objects, which as you know, interact by invoking methods. An object consists of :

- State: It is represented by attributes of an object. It also reflects the properties of an object.
- Behavior: It is represented by methods of an object. It also reflects the response of an object to other objects.
- Identity: It gives a unique name to an object and enables one object to interact with other objects.

Is `Object` a datatype in Java?

Comment: You can read all about Object yourself, here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: All non primitive datatypes are of type Object, or it's family if you intended to ask that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Object a datatype in java?

Yes.

Every class in Java is a datatype and `Object` is a class which means that it too is a datatype. It is special as it is a superclass of every class in Java.